# How does this sum go to $0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

http://www.math.chalmers.se/Math/Grundutb/CTH/tma401/0304/handinsolutions.pdf

In problem (2), at the very end it says

$$\left(\sum_{k = n+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2}\right)^{1/2} \to 0$$

I don't see how that is accomplished. I understand the sequence might, but how does the sum $$\left ( \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}+ \frac{1}{(n+2)^2} + \frac{1}{(n+3)^2} + \dots \right)^{1/2} \to 0$$?

Is one allowed to do the following?

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left ( \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}+ \frac{1}{(n+2)^2} + \frac{1}{(n+3)^2} + \dots \right)^{1/2} \to 0$$

$$=\left (\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}+ \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{(n+2)^2} + \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{(n+3)^2} + \dots \right)^{1/2} \to 0$$

$$(0 + 0 + 0 + \dots)^{1/2} = 0$$

Comment: is it $\frac{1}{k^2}$?

Comment: If a series converges then the "sum of its tail" goes to zero. If $\sum_{n=1} a_n$ converges then $\sum_{n>K} a_n$ goes to zero as $K$ goes to infinity.

Comment: Your limit argument is not correct. Such an approach only applies to finitely many terms. If you are applying a limit to a sum of a few things then you can take the limits individually and add them if they exist. But when you have  limit of a sum of infinitely many terms you cannot take the limit of individual terms and then add them later. When you study Riemann sum you see a clear example of this.

Comment: This really isn't a series.  It's a sequence, and part of the definition of each term is a series.  But it's important to understand that you really have two limits here, one as $n$ goes to $\infty$, but another as $k$ goes to $\infty$, which is evaluated for each $n$.

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/302635/prove-lim-j-rightarrow-infty-sum-k-1-infty-fraca-kjk-0/302642#302642).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One can forget about the square root part for a while. Note that $\dfrac{1}{k^2}\lt \dfrac{1}{(k-1)k}$.

But $\dfrac{1}{(k-1)k}=\dfrac{1}{k-1}-\dfrac{1}{k}$. Thus your sum is less than 
$$\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+2}+\frac{1}{n+2}-\frac{1}{n+3}+\cdots.$$
Note the wholesale cancellation: the above sum is $\dfrac{1}{n}$.

It follows that your original expression is less than $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$.

**Remark:** Treating infinite "sums" as if they were long finite sums is a dangerous business that can all too easily give wrong answers. If one has experience with a particular series, such as the convergent series $\sum_1^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$, then one can "see" that the tail must approach $0$. In fact, the issue is precisely the issue of the convergence of $\sum_1^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$.

Answer (score 5):

It turns out that

$$\sum_{k=N+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2} = \int_0^{\infty} dx \frac{x }{e^x-1} e^{-N x}$$

You can prove this by factoring out an $e^{x}$ from the denominator and Taylor expanding the resulting denominator.  In any case, by integrating by parts, you can show that

$$\sum_{k=N+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2} = \frac{1}{N} + O\left( \frac{1}{N^2}\right)$$

In fact, you can get a full asymptotic expansion of the sum over $N$ using this integral.  In any case, though, this shows how the sum vanishes as $N \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: I think this answer may be better for the OP than the more abstract answers.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, this is a result I first saw derived in Bender & Orszag, and I think is a little pearl more people should have in their toolbox.

Answer (score 3):

First note that
$$\dfrac1{k^2} \leq \int_{k-1}^k\dfrac{dx}{x^2} \,\,\,\, (\text{Why?})$$
Hence,
$$\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \dfrac1{k^2} \leq \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \int_{k-1}^k\dfrac{dx}{x^2} = \int_n ^{\infty} \dfrac{dx}{x^2} = \dfrac1n$$
Hence, we have that
$$0 \leq \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \dfrac1{k^2} \leq \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac1n = 0$$
Your argument to prove it is incorrect, since in general you cannot swap two limits to conclude the answer. For instance, by your same argument, you will also get that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\dfrac1{n} + \dfrac1{n} + \cdots + \dfrac1n + \cdots \right) = 0$$which is clearly false.

Answer (score 2):

In general we have if $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k$ converges then the tail of the sereis $\sum_{k=N}^{\infty}a_k$must go to zero to see this consider $$s_n=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k$$ then we have$s_n\to\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k$ that means for any $\epsilon$ we there is $N$ such that$$|\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k-s_N|<\epsilon$$ but $$|\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k-s_N|=|\displaystyle\sum_{k=N}^{\infty}a_k|$$ thus, $$|\displaystyle\sum_{k=N}^{\infty}a_k|<\epsilon$$ since epsilon was arbitrary we conclude that$\sum_{k=N}^{\infty}a_k\to 0$.
 as for your example we know by the integral test that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}$ is convergent Thus, by what I wrote we must have $\sum_{k=N}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}\to 0.$
 **Remark:** of course if $\sum_{k=N}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}\to 0.$ then $(\sum_{k=N}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2})^{1/2}\to 0.$

Answer (score 1):

Since the sum $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}$ [is convergent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem), you can make the "tail" of the sum ($\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}$) as small as you want.

Explicitly, since $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$, for any $\epsilon>0$, you can find an $n$ such that $\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^2}<\epsilon$.

In that case, the tail sums form a strictly decreasing sequence of positive numbers, which can be made smaller than any $\epsilon>0$.

That is convergence to 0! :)

Naturally if the expression converges to zero, so does the square root of the expression.

Comment: $\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^2}$ Are you sure you can break up the sum like that? $n$ is a variable here no?

Comment: @sizz I don't see why $n$ being a variable is scary: it's true for every $n$. The thing on the left hand side is an absolutely convergent series, and it's clearly equal to the right hand side.

Comment: @sizz in fact you can see two other duplicates of my answer already :/

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $\sum \frac{1}{k^2}$ is convergent.  If I invoke Cauchy's Convergence Criterion, the proof of this sum is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

A [related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/302635/prove-lim-j-rightarrow-infty-sum-k-1-infty-fraca-kjk-0/302642#302642). Note that,

$$ \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2}= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(k+n)^2} \leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2} <\infty, $$

which implies that the series

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(k+n)^2} $$

converges uniformly. So, we have

$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt{  \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}  } = \sqrt{\lim_{n\to \infty}  \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}  } = \sqrt{\lim_{n\to \infty}  \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(k+n)^2}  } = \sqrt{  \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{(k+n)^2} }=0. $$

Notice that, the function $\sqrt{x}$ is a continuous function for $x>0$, which justifies changing the operation $\lim f(a_n) = f( \lim a_n )$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{%
\pars{\sum_{k = n + 1}^{\infty}\ {1 \over k^{2}}}^{1/2}} =
\pars{\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\ {1 \over k^{2}} -
\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\ {1 \over k^{2}}}^{1/2}
\\[5mm] = &\
\braces{\zeta\pars{2} -
\bracks{-{1 \over n} + \zeta\pars{2} + 2\int_{n}^{\infty}{\braces{x} \over x^{3}}\dd x}}^{1/2}
\end{align}
where I used a [zeta function identity](https://dlmf.nist.gov/25.2.E8). Moreover,
$$
0 < 2\int_{n}^{\infty}{\braces{x} \over x^{3}}\dd x <
2\int_{n}^{\infty}{\dd x \over x^{3}} = {1 \over n^{2}}
$$
Then,
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{%
\pars{\sum_{k = n + 1}^{\infty}\ {1 \over k^{2}}}^{1/2}} =
\bracks{{1 \over n} - 2\int_{n}^{\infty}{\braces{x} \over x^{3}}\dd x}^{1/2}
\\[5mm] &\
\bbx{\to \color{red}{\large 0}\ \mbox{as}\ n \to \infty}
\\ &
\end{align}